# What means "Estimated Savings" in Google Lighthouse?

Tags: pagespeed, lighthouse, pagespeed-insights, web-performance

Does anybody know what is the meaning of [Estimated Savings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYHLU.png) in Google Lighthouse (or PageSpeed Insights) report?

I can save 3.6 s. Byt of what? Page Load Time? It is impossible to find it anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

From [this comment](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/lighthouse/issues/8740#issuecomment-487962143):

> the "estimated savings" time in most of our opportunities is derived exactly from the estimated impact to the TTI metric.